# What is the meaning of "one" in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

The sentence, from the Wikipedia article on Thomas Pynchon:

> Indeed, claims that Pynchon was the Unabomber or a sympathizer with the Waco Branch Davidians after the 1993 siege were upstaged in the mid-1990s by the invention of an elaborate rumor insinuating that Pynchon and **one** "Wanda Tinasky" were the same person.

Would "a certain" fit here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One** in this context indeed refers to a person. However, the person that **one** refers to is anonymous rather than very well known. So the emphasis, with this kind of structures, is on the anonymity of the person in question.

Answer (score 1):

It would. Actually **one** in this case can be safely omitted.

*one* in this context is a formal way of referring to *a person*, so the following are valid:

> that Pynchon and a person named "Wanda Tinasky"
>   that Pynchon and a "Wanda Tinasky"
>   that Pynchon and "Wanda Tinasky"